# Cost of carry when holding a foreign ccy bond

Tags: fixed-income, cross-currency-basis

In the search of yield holding HY bonds in EM markets seems to be a theme that gains traction. In order to calculate the P&L correctly I just wanted to see I have it correct!

Assumption is

- Borrow cash (at internal cost)
- Sell USD, buy Local ccy at X Forward Points (negative or positive depends on the curve shape)
- Now adjust for duration to find the cost of holding time in basis points

For example Chilean Peso (CLP) Bonds:

Buy CLP 1m @ 803 vs spot @ 800 = -3 peso per a month = 37500 per 10mm USD

Buy a 10y bond with Dur = ~8k

37500/8000 = cost of carry per a month

Is this assumption correct or I am missing something?